# Free open source antivirus for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, antivirus

I'm looking for some reliable and free antivirus that's open source.  I've come across ClamAV, but according to few websites, it is not that good.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please detail exactly why ClamAV is not good for you.

Comment: This is way to broad and as Nicolas said, you did not provide a reason to why ClamAC is not a good option. Please add specific requirements to help narrow down your question and read our [Question Quality Guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/133).

Answer (score 1):

Ranking Anti-Virus performance is not an easy task. First of all, you have not specified why ClamAV is not an optimal choice for you, so this makes things difficult.

Here are a few Anti-Virus programs that meet your requirements (Gratis, Open Source):

1. [Nixory](http://nixory.sourceforge.net/)
2. [MoonSecure AntiVirus](http://www.moonsecure.com/df/)
3. [OpenAntiVirus](http://www.openantivirus.org/)

Now, in my opinion, the only website review I would trust for Anti-Virus would be [AV-Comparitives](http://www.av-comparatives.org/) but this does not cover what you're after. [This](http://www.av-comparatives.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/avc_linux_2015_en.pdf) is the closest I could find.

Furthermore, there are *many functions* that an Anti-Virus can perform, which you have not specified it have:

- An Anti-Virus with Phising Link Scanners
- An Anti-Virus with its own inbuilt Firewall
- An Anti-Virus that detects Trojans, Rootkits, Spyware and possibly bloatware

Now I have not installed ClamAV but I have done some research and there are many complaints about heuristic but to be honest **I would not trust most of the reviews, the users do not appear to be too computer savy**.

Some other reviews indicate that ClamAV only detects *62%* of known virus', so I would assume it under resourced.

I cannot make a legitimate suggestion as **none of these products** have any decent (or trustworthy reviews). We're not security experts here (or all of us are not), so there is little we could suggest.

All seem to be lightweight and have the same *basic function* - it's really a question of how complete the Virus Database are (and how frequently they are updated), and none of this information is easily obtained.